# AdMob public campaign - Why is it asking what ad unit to use?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I've been struggling to setup an AdMob public campaign to try and get new users to an app. When I go to my AdMob console I setup a campaign like this:

[AdMob Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x46TS.png)

And then I hit continue and the page then asks me to fill in this part:

[AdMob Console Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfsmH.png)

Which has me very confused. I used to make ad campaigns in the old AdMob way, but now I'm looking at this like its some kind of house ad (even though I select direct sold) which is asking me which of my own ad units I'd like to use - which makes sense for a house ad campaign, but I'm trying to make a public campaign?

**It won't let me continue without selecting at least one ad unit from one of my existing apps - so what in the world is going on? Is this not how I am meant to create public ad campaigns?**

Could it have something to do with the fact that the app I intend to advertise about, only went live yesterday on google play?

SIMILAR QUESTION THAT HAS GONE UNANSWERED:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96005/how-to-promote-my-own-apps-with-admob-after-august-2016

VAGUE INFO FROM GOOGLE:
(Can't post more links) support.google.com/admob/answer/7028917

Do I need to use adwords now to do public campaigns? Hope somebody knows what is going on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question, and you've actually provided the answer. The last URL you listed contains the important bit:

> Each AdMob user has a [Google AdWords](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6349091) account. Your AdWords account was either created when you signed up for AdMob or your existing AdWords account was connected to your AdMob account during sign up. You can use your AdWords account to run [paid ad campaigns](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2567043), particularly [universal app campaigns](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6247380).

The Promote tab in the AdMob console worked as a second front-end for a small fraction of AdWords functionality. Every AdMob publisher has an AdWords account under the hood, and that tab was essentially a slimmed-down interface for it. Rather than continuing to duplicate AdWords tech within AdMob, the team decided to start directing publishers directly to AdWords, and Universal App Campaigns in particular.

If you haven't seen [Universal App Campaigns](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6247380), I highly recommend checking them out. You can set a budget, upload a set of assets (or have them pulled from the App/Play store), and AdWords will automatically create ads for you in a variety of formats (mobile, search, even YouTube). It'll then run them, see which ones get the most installs, and put your budget to work where it's most successful.

So while you no longer have access to the Promote tab in AdMob, you can access AdWords directly, and take advantage of its more powerful and cost-effective ways to promote your apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did ultimately find that out through trial and error, but this should hopefully help others!